# Mysql takes very long time to retrieve results

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-workbench

I have problem with MySQL, where it takes very long time to retrieve result when I execute "select" operation on more than one table at the same time.

```
 SELECT movielens_rating_ds.ID, movielens_rating_ds.UserID, movielens_rating_ds.MovieID,movielens_ds.Movie_Title,movielens_rating_ds.Rating,movielens_ds.Movie_Genre, imdb_movies.Description FROM movielens_rating_ds, movielens_ds, imdb_movies where movielens_rating_ds.MovieID = movielens_ds.Movie_ID and movielens_ds.Movie_Title = replace(imdb_movies.Title,'\"','') and movielens_rating_ds.UserID=1
```

Also, when I try to retrieve result in java it does not return. 
Any help with this, is highly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess you actually want to provide some join information to those tables, otherwise it'll be providing a lot more results than you expect.

Specifically - if you provide no join information, it'll return a result row for every combination of rows from each table. So two tables of 1000 rows each will result in 1000000 result rows.

Comment: Thank you @Alan Dixon for your reply. Actually, no exist relation between these table such as foreign key ..etc, but I have "imdb_movies" before and then I found "movielens_ds" and "movieslens_rating_ds" tables. Where "imdb_movies" and "movielens_ds" tables shared with movies' names and "movielens_ds" and "movieslens_rating_ds" tables shared with movies' ids, so from these information I'm trying to connect these three tables and retrieve data for each user that I have in the database. It returns correct result when I tried to retrieve in mysql browser, but it takes very long time.

Comment: Create an index on all fields used for your JOINs.

Comment: It works with me many thanks @Alan Dixon :)